# Unable to autoload classes from PHPExcel

Tags: php, phpexcel

I've been struggeling with this during the last couple of hours :

On my computer (Ubuntu x64, php7.0, apache2  ), I have been able to use PHPExcel, with a piece of homemade software.

On the other hand, I have to deploy on a server (CentOs x64 (Not up to date) php 5.3.3 httpd) which i cannot upgrade and on this server the PHPExcel classes won't load.

You will find enclosed my own autoload, phpexcel autoloader, and the include file :

Caller file :

```
include_once 'PHPExcel.php';
include_once 'PHPExcel/IOFactory.php';
if ( class_exists('PHPExcel')  )
  error_log('phpexcel loaded');
else
  error_log('phpexcel notloaded');
...
...
...
$colonnes = array();
$locale = 'fr_fr';
PHPExcel_Settings::setLocale($locale);
```

Fails when calling PHPExcel_Settings::setLocale($local);

My autoloader :

```
function __autoload($class_name) {
    $fichierClasse = $_SESSION['PATH_SERVER'] . '/classes/' .$class_name . '.php';
    if (file_exists($fichierClasse))
        require_once $fichierClasse;
    else
        return false;
     }
```

and the log says : "Class PHPExcel_Setting not found".

If anyone has the tinest clue that would explain why it isn't loading it would be very appriciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, as I went back to work this morning I removed the __autoload() function from my own autoloader :

```
spl_autoload_register(function ($class_name) {
    $fichierClasse = $_SESSION['PATH_SERVER'] . '/classes/' .$class_name . '.php';
    if (file_exists($fichierClasse))
        require_once $fichierClasse;
    else
        return false;
});
```

It worked !

Indeed, the _autoload() function was competing with the Loader used by PHPExcel even though it registerd the __autoload() function with spl_autoload_register :

```
public static function Register() {
    if (function_exists('__autoload')) {
        //    Register any existing autoloader function with SPL, so we don't get any clashes
        spl_autoload_register('__autoload');
    }
    //    Register ourselves with SPL
    return spl_autoload_register(array('PHPExcel_Autoloader', 'Load'));
}   //    function Register()
```

I still don't really understand why it was working on my computer using PHP7.0 and not on the server using PHP5.3.3

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

First, debug the output of your function __autoload(). Maybe a var_dump help you. Verify if the value of variable $fichierClasse is the same of the your file you need require. Exists many questions about your problem. Make more tests especific of the outputs. Now I can't help you more with only this.

Comment: My __autoload() function is working with my own classes, every single one of them is loaded, PHPExcel class is loaded, so as PHPExcel_autoloader.
The main question is why would all the classes load on my computer with php7.0 and not on the server with php5.3.3. I can't manage to find which function has been deprecated our changed...
Thanks for your reply

Comment: Thanks Iago, you helped me a lot, I put a lot of error_log in the functions and it revealed that PHPExcel_Setting class was handled by __autoload but when it failed to load it, it didn't pass it to the next autloader.

Comment: Great! If you need more help, just say!